# Installing Python 3.2.x on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, python

I'm completely new to Ubuntu (and any OS outside of Windows). I would like to use my newly formatted and installed Ubuntu desktop to code in Python. The problem is, I don't know how to install the version of Python I would like to use (>= 3.2).

I am running a 32 bit 12.04.2 LTS install and I currently have `Python-3.2.4.tgz` sitting in my downloads folder but I do not know where to go from here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply type the following in the terminal:

> sudo apt-get install python3

After you typed in your system password, it installs python 3 and you then have two versions of Python installed: version 2.7 and 3.2. If you now want to start a program using python3 you can simply type:

> python3 myProgram.py

If I may suggest a good IDE for writing Python; use Spyder.. :)

Happy coding!

Comment: @Takkat, I Realised it would not make use of my downloaded package immediately, but I only wanted a 3.2 family Python installation to run alongside Pygame 1.9.1. Whilst 3.2.3 is not most updated in the 3.2 family, it should suit my simple needs effectively. Thankyou for your concern.

Comment: @user157701: that is perfectly fine then - just wanted to point this out. You may want to upvote/accept the above answer in case it helped you :)